# Отфильтровать таблицу по ключевым словам в тексте

Tags: python, pandas, словари, текст, работа-с-текстом

У меня есть большая таблица вот такого плана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно создать новую таблицу со строками исходной таблицы, в которых в столбце "описание" содержатся слова "собран, соберут".

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @strawdog, это не учебное задание. Это моя реальная таблица, там еще 600+ строк. И я пытаюсь разобраться, как мне в принципе подойти к этой задаче) 

Из этих 600+ строк мне нужны только те, где в текстах содержатся слова "собран, соберут". Я буду благодарна за любую помощь и идеи, как мне лучше реализовать решение. 
Одна из идей - перевести содержимое таблицы в словарь, а потом уже обработать текст.

Comment: Вам уже подсказали в первом комментарии, куда смотреть. Пока ваш вопрос выглядит не как просьба о помощи, а как просьба решить проблему за вас.

Comment: @strawdog, мне очень жаль, что мой вопрос вызвал у вас такую реакцию. 
я посмотрела первую подсказку, благодаря ей я уже вышла на верный путь решения.

Comment: Не стоит сожалеть о том, что легко исправить в будущем. Если у вас возникнут вопросы или трудности при решении конкретных задач, добро пожаловать с вашим кодом и описанием проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Так как есть ненулевая вероятность, что кто-то задавался подобным вопросом, напишу свое решение проблемы, на которое я вышла благодаря комментарию @splash58

```
table=pd.read_csv('30.csv', sep=';') 
result=table[table['text'].str.contains
      ('собра+| соберут', case = False, regex=True )== True]
```

На выходе получаем таблицу result, в которой в столбце Text будут содержаться только удовлетворяющие условию тексты.

Comment: Рекомендуется использовать синтаксис `table.loc[...]`, а не просто `table[...]`